# Persisting server request in android

Tags: android, room

Is it a good choice if i persist  server request data in database and manage them without any user interaction ?
Is it good practice persisting  requests at all ?

Comment: It depends on the use case I think. What is specifically your use case of persisting a request data?

Comment: For example for retrying automatically request if they just failed.
 without user approve it to retry

Comment: Not a good idea. Data related to UI should be fetched when the app is running. But data not related to UI could be fetched any time that is necessary.